# sort problem with <xsl:sort ...> in .NET 4

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, c#-4.0, xsl-fo

I have a problem when I compile my program with .NET 4 as target framework. The sorting with  does not work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace ExampleSortProblemServer
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // argument is the filename
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(args[0]);

        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        XmlResourceResolver resolver = new XmlResourceResolver(typeof (IReport));
        xslt.Load(args[1]);

        String foStr = CreateFO(xmlDocument, xslt, resolver);

        Console.WriteLine(foStr);
    }

    public static string CreateFO(XmlNode doc, XslCompiledTransform xslt, XmlResolver resolver)
    {
        string fo;

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(doc.OuterXml))
        {
            using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            xslt.Transform(xmlTextReader, null, xmlTextWriter, resolver);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                            throw;
                        }
                        stringWriter.Flush();
                        fo = stringWriter.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fo;
    }
  }
}
```

The Data is "Daten.xml":

```
<daten>
<employees>
    <name>Knight</name>
    <name>Cook</name>
    <name>Superman</name>
    <name>Yoda</name>
    <name>Albright</name>
</employees>
</daten>
```

The Stylesheet is "Daten.xsl":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="daten" select="*[local-name()='daten']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$daten">
        <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(*[local-name()='employees']/*[local-name()='name']" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can call the program with:
    ExampleSortProblemServer.exe Daten.xml Daten.xsl

The expected order should be:

Albright Cook Knight Superman Yoda

Any idea what is incorrect?

Comment: consecutive `using` declarations do not need curly braces; the code is much more readable if you omit all but the innermost pair (and in this case the standard indenting doesn't indent the consecutive usings either.

Comment: Also, the XmlTextWriter constructor is deprecated in favor of XmlWriter.Create

Comment: finally, it's generally best practice not to do general exception logging inside helper methods; best to do that as globally as possible.  Only catch exceptions you can actually fix.

Comment: Readability depends on the person... A hint to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because you are trying to sort `daten` and not the `names`.

For example, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()='daten']/*[local-name()='employees']/*[local-name()='name']">
      <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with your input "Daten.xml":

```
<daten>
  <employees>
    <name>Knight</name>
    <name>Cook</name>
    <name>Superman</name>
    <name>Yoda</name>
    <name>Albright</name>
  </employees>
</daten>
```

produces this output:

```
Albright Cook Knight Superman Yoda
```

---

**EDIT**

The stylesheet only needs a little updating to handle the XML input you added as an answer.

This input:

```
<daten>
  <employees>
    <employee>
      <name>Knight</name>
      <forename>Peter</forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Knight</name>
      <forename>Gilbert</forename>
    </employee>     
    <employee>
      <name>Cook</name>
      <forename>Thomas</forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Cook</name>
      <forename>Charles</forename>
    </employee>     
    <employee>
      <name>Superman</name>
      <forename>Kal-El</forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Yoda</name>
      <forename></forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Albright</name>
      <forename>Peter</forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Albright</name>
      <forename>Charles</forename>
    </employee> 
    <employee>
      <name>Albright</name>
      <forename>Mark</forename>
    </employee>     
  </employees>
</daten>
```

with the updated stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()='daten']/*[local-name()='employees']/*[local-name()='employee']">
      <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="name"/>
      <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="forename"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="forename">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the output you wanted:

```
Albright Charles
Albright Mark
Albright Peter
Cook Charles
Cook Thomas
Knight Gilbert
Knight Peter
Superman Kal-El
Yoda
```

Comment: This seems to work so far.

**But:**

 1. The Output should be without the "name" tags:<br>
     Albright<br>
     Cook<br>
     Knight<br>
     Superman<br>
     Yoda<br>
 
 2. What would be the solution if I have several levels of sorting? Eg.
       1. Level:   name
       2. Level:   forname
       ...

    So to have a result like:<br>
       Albright Mark<br>
       Albright Peter<br>
       Cook Charles<br>
       Cook Thomas<br>
       ...<br>
<br>

Comment: 1. The first version of the stylesheet was just to demonstrate the proper sorting (to get you started). I modified it so you get exactly the requested output. (I added a template to match `name`.)
2. Can you please add another sample XML instance so I can see what you're describing with the name/forname?

Comment: @jahuer1 - Please see my edit for a slightly modified stylesheet that produces the output you want.

Comment: @DevNull clean solution +1. Perhaps, you can omit `order`, as "ascending" is default, and, in place of `local-name()='xxx'` use `self::xxx`.

Comment: Good suggestions @empo. I left the `order` in so that the OP could see how the order could be easily changed (without asking another question). I also left the `local-name()` in the stylesheet since that is what the OP had in his/her stylesheet. I like `self::xxx` much better. It is a lot cleaner. I also liked your Yoda comment on the other "answer". :-)

Comment: @DevNull you are perfectly right in leaving OP code as is, as much as possible, even if it's hard :)

Comment: I played a little around. It seems when using .NET 4, sorting is done regardless of the order you give for which tag (name or forename).

Comment: I played a little around. It seems when using .NET 4, sorting is done regardless of the order you give for which tag (name or forename). Try once <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="forename"/><xsl:sort order="ascending" select="name"/>. You should expect "Yoda  Albright Charles Cook Charles...". Under .NET 3.5 this works. But .NET 4 produces "Albright Charles Albright Mark Albright Peter ..." :-(. It's even getting worse if you add a <salary> to each <employee>. Add eg. <xsl:sort order="descending" select="salary"/> as last sort criteria. Hint: 2* "Cook Charles", one with 4000, other 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Here an extended xml file:

```
<daten>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>Knight</name>
        <forename>Peter</forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Knight</name>
        <forename>Gilbert</forename>
    </employee>     
    <employee>
        <name>Cook</name>
        <forename>Thomas</forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Cook</name>
        <forename>Charles</forename>
    </employee>     
    <employee>
        <name>Superman</name>
        <forename>Kal-El</forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Yoda</name>
        <forename></forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Albright</name>
        <forename>Peter</forename>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Albright</name>
        <forename>Charles</forename>
    </employee> 
    <employee>
        <name>Albright</name>
        <forename>Mark</forename>
    </employee>     
</employees>
</daten>
```

The result should be:

Albright Charles
Albright Mark
Albright Peter
Cook Charles
Cook Thomas
Knight Gilbert
Knight Peter
Superman Kal-El
Yoda

Comment: I'd like to have a collegue with name _Yoda_.